# Migration issue : Only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following migration :

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('level',5)->unsigned();
            $table->string('username',60);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('country',3);
            $table->string('about',150);
            $table->integer('balance')->unsigned();
            $table->string('photo_url');
            $table->string('photo_id',50);
            $table->string('search_tag');

            $table->tinyInteger('is_bots');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

The error it throws :

```
[PDOException]                                                                                                                                         
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Everything seems good, I have one primary key that is auto increment etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$table->integer('level',5)->unsigned();
```

That line is the problem. `integer`'s second argument is not a size. The second argument is for (bool) auto increment. So you are telling this field to be an auto increment field.

`Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint@integer`:

```
public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
```